# How to modify android system application

Tags: android, apk

I made a little modification to the default Phone application of Android 4.2.2 from AOSP. I want to replace the stock app with the one i modified. When I try to remove the stock app and place the modified app (and then reboot), the phone app fails. I'm guessing it has got something to do with apk signing. Is there any way to solve this?

My device is rooted and i also have the factory image.

Comment: Can you define "fails"?

Comment: Does it even install? It would not in case the signatures don't match.

Comment: I haven't tried to install it via the Package Manager. I simply remounted system directory (making it 'rw') and placed the apk under /system/apps/ directory. After a reboot it kept failing to open the phone app. "com.android.phone process stopped working".

Comment: Try this tool: forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2326604 It makes signing much easier, and there are clear instructions available.

Comment: Thank you @Mdlc but that only helps if you are only modifying resources (xml and stuff) and if you can understand smali